# Sheet material that does not adhere to wood glue

Tags: adhesive

I am looking for some sheet material (as in paper, cellophane etc.) that wood glue will not stick to to use as an insulator between glue drippage on one side and something on the other side to which I don't want it glued by the excess glue.

E.g. if I am biscuit joining two long boards and using wood glue with biscuits, I need to clamp the whole thing together and if that clamp is touching the joint, the excess glue will stick the clamp as well, which I obviously don't want.  So is there some material that can be used as an insulator blocking the glue coming through to the other side but also not sticking to it?  Cellophane sheets of some sort (which?) come to mind because they seem very smooth, i.e. not adhesive.

Comment: You can put furniture paste wax on many things (*workbench, clamps Etc*) , it will shed glue like water off an "amphibient".

Answer (score 3):

I have used wax paper over surfaces to keep it clean. Used tape over the shafts of bar clamps, small pieces of cellophane between blocks of wood that was clamped in place to keep faces of planks aligned while edge gluing.

Answer (score 1):

Wood glue will peel right off of pretty much any type of poly sheeting. Depending on how large of a surface you need to cover and how much abuse it needs to withstand, you can use pretty much anything from painter's plastic to garbage bags.

Answer (score 1):

I've used cling film.  It's very thin so will follow contours extremely well.

I a few instances of gluing in steel studs with a nut screwed on (to keep the stud perpendicular to the mounting surface), I've wrapped the stud with PTFE tape from the plumbing world.  That allows the nut to come off smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that glue does not seem to stick to the slick side of what is sold at "markerboard" at big box suppliers, intended for use with dry erase markers like in a conference room or something like that.  I have also found that a surface painted with a couple of coats of counter top paint (also sold at some big box suppliers) tends to resist glue.